# What's the meaning of dividing percentages?

Tags: statistics, percentages, ratio

I have a question regarding the meaning of dividing percentages. Imagine the following situation:

We have two cities: city A and city B. In city A there are 58,000 residents, of which 29,000 are women. In city B there are 120,000 residents, of which 96,000 are women. So, in city A 50% of the residents are women whereas in city B 80% are women.

If we want to compare the percentages of women in both populations (A vs B) and we do the following:

100 x $\frac{0.8}{0.5}$ = 160%

What does this mean? I guess it is that for every woman in city A there is 1.6 woman in city B, but I don't know if there is another useful interpretation, especially in terms of percentage. I would like to say something like: "there are about 60% more women in city B than in city A", but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Thanks!

Comment: "If we want to compare the percentages of women in both populations " In what sense? we have a percentage of women of 50% in population A and of 80% in B: this is the comparison.

Comment: I'd like to say something like "there are 60% more women in B than in A" or something like that. To sum up, use only a number to compare both, not saying 50% in A and 80% in B.

Comment: Ok, in that case you have an excess of 80%-50%=30% on the 50% percentage of women in A. If so, $\dfrac {30}{50}=60$.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the excess and I really prefer that interpretation. It's just that I've found the division in one old document and I don't understand the meaning of it.

Comment: For issues like this I would phrase the relations in terms of [percentage points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro That exactly was my idea as well. Nice link.

Comment: @callculus42: FYI, I didn't realize you had already mentioned "percentage points" in another comment. Before writing my comment (which time stamps clearly show was after your comment), I glanced over the answers and comments (apparently not all that carefully) and didn't see any mention of "percentage point", so I googled (expecting to find a Wikipedia page, which I did) for a web page link to give (so I wouldn't have to explain it myself).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just comparing percentages, then you cannot really say anything that compares absolute values. So, statements like "there are this many more women in A compared to B" are right out. This is because, with only percentages, you don't really know the sizes of the two cities. For exmaple, one city could be 1000 times bigger, and have many more women even if only 10% of the population are women.

The figure 160% you calculated simply tells you that the percentage of women in city B is 60% higher than it is in city A. But that is confusing, because when you say "80% is 60% bigger than 50%", it is hard to follow which percentage pertains to what (the first and last % sign speak of the ratio of women, while the second % sign speaks of the ratio of the percentages, so it's "ratio of ratio"). Also, it's even more confusing since you could also say that "80% is 30% bigger than 50%".

So it really pays to not just blindly plug numbers into equations, but think about what the numbers mean. In your case, the best explanation I can think of would be

> If the two cities were equally sized, then city B would have 60% more women than city A.

Notice the "if" in the beginning: assuming the two cities are equally sized is needed to avoid comparing absolute values.

Alternatively, we could also say:

> A representative sample of city B's population shall have 60% more women than an equally sized representative sample of city A's population.

Comment: I think the distinction between percentage(s) and percentage point(s) is a good way.

Comment: "If the two cities were equally sized, then city B would have 60% more women than city A".This is what confuses me. If city A and city B were equally sized (let's say 100 residents to make it easier) and in city A 50 were women (50%) and in city B 80 were women (80%), how can we say there are 60% more women in city B than in city A? Wouldn't it be 30% more women in city B than in city A (80% - 50%)?

Comment: @questions135 80 is 60% more than 50.

Answer (score 0):

Percentages of percentages often cause confusion, and it is sensible to avoid them.

- You might say there are $\frac{96000}{29000} \approx 3.31$ *times as many women* in City B as in City A.   Calling this "$231\%$ more women" may lead to misunderstanding.
- You might say the proportion of women in City B  is $80\%-50\%=30$ *[percentage points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point)* higher than in City A.   Calling this "$30\%$ more women" may lead to misunderstanding.
- To use a technical term, you might say the *[relative risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk)* of being a woman in City B is $\frac{80\%}{50\%}=1.60$ times that of being a woman in City A. Calling this "$60\%$ more women" may lead to misunderstanding.

There are more alternative descriptions. For example the [*odds ratio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) for women between the two cities is  $\dfrac{\frac{96000}{120000-96000}}{\frac{29000}{58000-29000}} =4$; this has the nice property that the odds ratio for men is $0.25$, which is its reciprocal, but the disadvantage that few people understand odds ratios.